# express.js's routing does not working well , when the path has the same part

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting routing like this using express.js

```
router.get('/', controller.showAll);
router.post('/', controller.add);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.delete);
router.delete('/')
router.get('/search/:target', todoController.search);
```

When I request '/search/:target' , sometimes it calls search method , but sometimes it calls showAll method.
It can be said to Delete method also.
But post,put methods are working fine.

I think it is because '/search/:target' includes '/' path , but I don't know how to identify the difference.
Is there any ways to avoid this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're right. It's because your `:target` param includes a `/`. Express is looking for a route that matches that pattern. Something like:
`/search/:something/something-else`

But it does not exist. So, it defaults to the root `/` route which uses the `showAll` method.

To fix this you should create another route to capture the search requests with a `/` in the param.

Perhaps something like:

```
router.get('/search/:target/:something', todoController.search);
```